# Next.js 14 tailwind css classes not working

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, next.js14

I am using Tailwind CSS with Next.js 14 in my new project but when I use Tailwind CSS classes in the `page.tsx` file, it doesn't work. I tried to change `tailwind.config.ts` and `tailwind.config.js` according to official documentation but still Tailwind is not working.

## postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

## tailwind.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

## page.tsx

```
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Home() {
  return (
   <p className="text-3xl font-bold underline"> hello world</p>
  )
}
```

## tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
  ],
  prefix: "y",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
```

i am using globels.css file in layout.jsx file
and my project-root relative path for the page.tsx if /app/page.tsx

Comment: What does your `tailwind.config.js` file contain? What is the project-root relative path of `page.tsx`? What CSS have you `import`ed in your app code?

Comment: thank you for the format tips. This is my first time asking questions in stack overflow so I am new to the format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set a [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) in your `tailwind.config.js` but you are not using it in your markup.

You could consider:

- Using the configured prefix in your markup like:

  ```html
  <p className="ytext-3xl yfont-bold yunderline">
  ```
- Removing the `prefix` key from `tailwind.config.js`.